# Visual Studio: quickly find build error in source

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, build, compiler-errors, text-editor

My programming workflow often involves sequences like this:

- build
- look at error list
- double click top error
- fix the error

Often though I have several editor windows open and it can take me a while to find the rather camouflaged icon in the indicator margin.  Sometimes it's even out of sight behind the error window.

Is there any way I can highlight the current error line in the source code so that I can find it more quickly?

Answer (score 2):

Pressing F8 in Visual studio take you to the errors

Answer (score 1):

Are you using resharper?

If not try and take a look at it, as far as i remember it allows you to customize how errors are displayed.

Comment: I use resharper in commercial environment- highliths lines, matches brackets, shows pre mature errors and suggestions, process source code for better intellisense.. its just all that VS does not offer. Not to pricey for personal licesne.. or student is cheap.

Comment: Then you should try and take a look at Coderush [DevExpress Coderush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/#maintc|features). I haven't used it  myself, but as far as I can see it contains more or less the features of resharper